# How to extract bit value from binary operation?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, binary

Consider the following code:

```
>> from pyspark.sql import Row, functions
>> mask = 0b10
>> test = 0b1100010
>> df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(a=mask, b=test)])
>> df.withColumn("c", df.a.bitwiseAND(df.b)).select(functions.col("c")).collect()
   [Row(c=2)]
```

I would like to adapt this code to perform a binary operation to extract the value of the 2nd byte of the variable `test`. As a result, I would like obtain 1 because the result is 2 in base 10 (10 in base 2).

If the variable `test` now equal to `0b11000`, I would like to obtain 0 because the result will be 0 in any base...

I tried to `cast` the result in `BinaryType` in order to have a representation of the operation in base 2 (for `test = 0b1100010` it should be `10`), convert this representation into a string one and extract the first char. But I got an exception while trying to `cast` to `BinaryType`.

**EDIT :**

I am using `pyspark 2.3.0`

**SOLUTION :**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType
mask = 0b10
test = 0b1100010
df = spark.createDataFrame([(mask, test)], ["a", "b"])

df = df.withColumn("bitwise", df.a.bitwiseAND(df.b))
df = df.withColumn("bitwise_str", df.bitwise.cast(StringType()))
df = df.withColumn("binary", F.conv(df.bitwise_str, 10, 2))
df = df.withColumn("boolean_result", F.substring(df.binary.cast(StringType()), 0, 1).cast(IntegerType()))

df.collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cast the c column into string and then move to base 2 using [conv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.conv.html) function

Comment: Thanks, I write the solution in the post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spark's [`bit_get`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#bit_get) (index is 0-based, so the 2nd bit is referenced by index 1)

```
bit_get(a & b, 1)
```

Getting 2nd bit from binary operation `a & b`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
mask = 0b10
test = 0b1100010
df = spark.createDataFrame([(mask, test)], ["a", "b"])

df.select(F.expr("bit_get(a & b, 1)").alias("c")).collect()
# [Row(c=1)]
```

(`expr` is needed, because `bit_get` is not yet directly available in PySpark.)

It's even simpler to get the bit from already existent column: `bit_get(b, 1)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify the version of pyspark. I am using pyspark 2.3.0 and bit_get is not available. Do you have any work around ?

Comment: @ZygD - nice solution! wasn't aware of this hidden function :)